# PHP class name from variable with "class not found" check?

Tags: php, class, exception

I'm trying to implement the strategy pattern in PHP, creating objects with variable variables as follows:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$myObject = new $className();
```

Is there a way to verify that $className exists as a Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[class_exists($className)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)